# Get difference between arrays with same objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, like this:

```
var a = [
    {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 1}, {id: 3}
];

var b = [
    {id: 1}, {id: 3}
];
```

I want to get the elements that array `a` has and array `b` doesn't. The expected outcome is:

```
[
    {id: 1}, {id: 2}
]
```

I tried this:

```
a.filter(x => b.indexOf(x) == -1);
```

And this:

```
a.filter(x => new Set(b).has(x) == false);
```

The problem with those two is that it treats `{id: 2}` from array A and `{id: 2}` from array B as different objects, so those two lines of code simply return the full array A.

Another difficulty, I need `{id: 1}` and `{id: 1}` to be treated as two different objects, even if they have the exact same properties and values inside.

In my actual code, I have objects which are more complex and have more properties, but the situation is the same.

Comment: @RolandStarke edited to change scenario which I'm facing, your code doesn't work.

Comment: where do you know which object is the shared object?

Comment: @NinaScholz if you're asking how I would know which objects are duplicate in the array, I don't.

Comment: how should i know this?

Comment: @NinaScholz I dunno, still thinking.

Comment: you need to state clearly what you want, and how to deal with objects with the same properties. Will they be same reference, something else? who knows..

Comment: @dashton with handling objects with the same properties, I want to treat them as different objects, so not the same reference. I did state that in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got this working:

```
function differenceOf(arr1, arr2) {
  var differences = $.extend(true, [], arr1); // creates clone
  var arr2Duplicate = $.extend(true, [], arr2);
arr2Loop:
  for(var i = 0; i < arr2Duplicate.length; i++) {
      var obj2 = arr2Duplicate[i];
      if(obj2 == null) continue;
differencesLoop:
      for(var j = 0; j < differences.length; j++) {
          var obj1 = differences[j];
          if(obj1 == null) continue;
          if(obj1.id == obj2.id) {
            differences.splice(j, 1);
            arr2Duplicate.splice(i, 1);
            i = -1;
            j = -1;
            break differencesLoop;
          }
      }
  }
  return differences;
}
```

I cloned the two arrays for future manipulation, so references would be removed and the original arrays wouldn't be affected. I set the first array to be the `differences` array, so I can delete the elements that appear in the other array.

I iterate through the second array and then inside that loop I iterate through the first array. Then, I check for equal ID's; if so, then I found an element that is in both arrays, so I simply remove it from the first array. I also remove the element from the second array to prevent duplicate comparison, and then I break out of the loop to prevent more deletion of elements with the same ID.

When I remove the elements, the loop is still going, and eventually it'll reach that empty slot where the element used to be, so I check if it's null; if so, skip and keep going.

After both loops finish, I'm left with an array that has the elements that are different, regardless of elements that have the same properties.

**EDIT**: I changed the jQuery each loops to standard for loops because when I tried to break out of the inner loop, it broke out of the outer loop as well. I fixed this by adding those GOTO labels, which fixed the breaking problem.

When I detected a duplicate, I also reset the indices back to -1, because when the loop continues, the index will increment and skip over objects, leading to incorrect data. I reset it to -1 so that when the code block finishes, it'll increment back to 0 and it'll scan the arrays over again.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a set and return the filtered array without the values of the set's id.

```js
var a = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 3 }],
    b = [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    s = new Set(b.map(({ id }) => id)),
    result = a.filter(({ id }) => !s.has(id));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: edited to change scenario which I'm facing, your code doesn't work.